# Illustrator export to .png problem (pixel will get bigger)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, dpi

First I create a file with 1000 px x 1000 px 300 dpi. 
After this, I create a artboard with 1000x1000 px. Now I filled it with a color. 
I click file > export > .png and save it.

Now the problem, I open this exported image to photoshop and see, the pixel size is bigger (4167px x 4167px - 300 dpi) than I create on illustrator.

So, how can I export png files with the correct size, which I set up on illustrator?

Comment: Illustrator does not have a DPI setting so there is not really a way for you to have a 300 DPI file in illustrator.

Answer (score 1):

The PPI setting you set when creating a new document is just for raster effects (e.g. drop shadows) and doesn't actually have any effect at all on your document (Illustrator is a vector program so has no resolution).

Pixels in Illustrator are actually just points and *always* correspond to 72 PPI....

So simple answer; export at 72 PPI.

Comment: The caveat is that now OP needs to know what really PPI means.

Comment: As a confirmation of this answer: 300/72 = approx. 4.167, which is why, when exporting to 300ppi the result was 4167 px